# no carga css de mi select2 php javascript

Tags: php, css, ajax, mvc, select2

Hola chicos tengo problemas con los estilos del select2 de sistema (MVC)

este es el select2

```
<select  id='id_cliente' name="id_cliente"  style="width: 100%;" class="select2ajaxCliente" >               </select>
```

este es el ajax

```
 ajax: {
    url: '../ajax/ajx_reportes.php?op=select2_clientes_get',
    dataType: 'json',
    processResults: function (data) {
    return {
      results: data
    };
    },
    cache: true
  }
  });
```

busque el nombre flores en el select2 y me da como resultado este json (se borrara los nombres de los clientes por seguridad)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero el problema esta en la vista del select2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo probé varias librerías que dan estilos a los Select y me di cuenta que al intentar insertar opciones en un Select con Ajax no cargan los estilos de la librería, al parecer es normal debido a que los estilos fueron cargados cuando se cargo la pagina por primera vez. Al final opte por no usar estas librerías cuando las opciones no están definidas al cargar la pagina(No aseguro que no haya solución).